# Cannot Seem to retrieve data from table in the order of the database table's column order

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sqlite

I want to to retrieve data from table in the order of the database table's column order.

Suppose my sql query is

```
String sql_string =  "select * "
                + "from CUSTOMER_INFO " 
                + "order by customer_last_name, customer_first_name";

Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
List<Map<String,Object>>  results =  session.createSQLQuery(sql_string)
    .setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
    .list();
```

In database, the table's column order is like `A,B,C,D`.
But when I retrieve the data and iterate through it, the entrySet is like `C,A,D,B`. (int,float,float,String)

I think the data is being retrieved based on its datatype.

I need the retrieved entrySet in the same order as it exists in database's table.

**I also tried specifying the column names in select query which was of no use.**

**`CUSTOMER_INFO`** is model class mapped to sqllite through hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_INFO")
public class CustomerInfo{
   @Column
    private int C;
    @Column
    private float A;
    @Column
    private String B;
    @Column
    private float D;

//getters and setters
}
```

Using Sqllite 3.6, hibernate, JSP.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just use `SELECT A,B,C,D FROM ...`? Or is it that you need a dynamic ordering?

Comment: As mentioned int question, I have already that solution but stills receive the data in form of `C,A,D,B`. I edited my question and bolden the part in which the same is mentioned.

Comment: sorry i overread that. i can only point to the documentation, i also have no real clue why it behaves like it does. What happens if you switch the Result-Transformer to return a list of lists? See `ToListResultTransformer`